# Create Outlook event, an activity that lasts 24 hours or longer, using VBA (not an appointment)

Tags: vba, outlook

There is a StackOverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713266/excel-vba-macro-create-an-outlook-calendar-event) that links how to make an Outlook "event" but it creates an appointment.

The differences can be read about in [The Difference Between Events, Appointments and Meetings (Outlook '13)](http://www.knowledgewave.com/blog/msoffice/outlook/whats-the-dif-events-appointments-and-meeting-requests-in-microsoft-outlook-2013.html).

How do I create an event, an activity that lasts 24 hours or longer, using VBA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The different between Appointment and Event is Events lasts 24 hours or longer, as you know Events do not appear as occupied blocks of time in the user’s calendar. Instead, they appear as banners*

*To create an all-day event using vba, you will need to set the [**AllDayEvent**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._appointmentitem.alldayevent.aspx) property of the [**AppointmentItem**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.appointmentitem.aspx) object to **true**. Then set the [**Start**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._appointmentitem.start.aspx) property to 12:00 A.M. (midnight) on the day you want the event to begin, and [**End**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._appointmentitem.end.aspx) property to 12:00 A.M. on the day after you want the event to end.*

---

> *VBA Example*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim Obj_Event As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Set Obj_Event = Application.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

    With Obj_Event
        .Subject = "ALL Day Event Example"
        .Location = "stackoverflow.com"
        .AllDayEvent = True
        .Start = Format("03/10/2018 12:00 AM")
        .End = Format("03/11/2018 12:00 AM")
        .Save
        .Display
    End With
End Sub
```

---

> *C# Example*

```
private void AllDayEventExample()
{
    Outlook.AppointmentItem appt = Application.CreateItem(
        Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem)
        as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
    appt.Subject = "Developer's Conference";
    appt.AllDayEvent = true;
    appt.Start = DateTime.Parse("6/11/2007 12:00 AM");
    appt.End = DateTime.Parse("6/16/2007 12:00 AM");
    appt.Display(false);
}
```

---

> *[MSDN: How to: Create an Appointment That Is an All-Day Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff184629.aspx)*

Comment: This solution correctly creates an event item. Thank you!