# How to reference the default Outlook calendar using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to create an event in Outlook using data from Excel.

```
Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim ObjAppt As Object
Dim objNamespace As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim OpenMAPIFolder As Object
Dim objCalendar As Object
   
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(9).Folders("Calendar")
Set ObjAppt = objFolder.Items.Add 'create task item
With ObjAppt
    .Body = Range("A1")
    .Start = Range("A17")
    .End = Range("B17")
    .AllDayEvent = True
    .ReminderSet = True
    .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 1440
    .Save
End With

Set ObjAppt = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objNamespace = Nothing
Set objOutlook = Nothing
```

It says that the folder name is incorrect.

Comment: I guess what I need to know is how can I get to the correct folder/calendar?  I looked at Outlook, and it clearly says that my default calendar is just called Calendar.  I don't know why it is having trouble finding it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49121400/4539709

Answer (score 0):

*To get to the default Calendar folder try*

> ```
> objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
> ```

*[NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder method (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getdefaultfolder)*

*also see [Reference Outlook folder from Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41476442/4539709)*

*https://stackoverflow.com/a/41476442/4539709*